# File open and write, can not get exception path to execute

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to gracefully handle the condition where too much trace memory is requested, resulting in failure of the memory allocation. Here is my python script, which has been extracted from the main script and reduced to just this issue (the 20 second sleep is just so that I can observe the memory allocation and free steps with `free -m`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import os
import time
import re
import site
import signal
import sys
import getopt
import Gnuplot
from numpy import *
from decimal import *

def set_trace_buffer_size():
    """ Set trace buffer size """

    try:
       open('/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb'
                 , 'w').write(memory)
       print('path is via the non-exception route ')
    except:
        print('IO error setting trace buffer size ')
        sys.exit(2)

def free_trace_buffer():
    """ Free the trace buffer memory """

    try:
       open('/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb'
                 , 'w').write("1")
    except:
        print('IO error freeing the trace buffer memory ')
        sys.exit(2)

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('  SIGINT: Forcing cleanup before exit.')
    # Free the memory
    free_trace_buffer()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

memory = "2500000"

set_trace_buffer_size()

print('Sleeping for 20 seconds')
time.sleep(int(20))

free_trace_buffer()
```

And I get this:

```
$ sudo ./test.py
close failed in file object destructor:
IOError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
path is via the non-exception route
Sleeping for 20 seconds
^C  SIGINT: Forcing cleanup before exit.
```

My question is: What am I doing wrong and how can I get it use the `except` path when the allocation fails?

I suppose I could always check the value after the return to see if it is what was asked for. Upon failure it seems to revert to the previous value.

Comment: "I suppose I could always check the value after the return" Check the value of what? You don't seem to be assigning any globals, mutating any values, or returning anything from any part of this.

Comment: @abarnert : What is posted is a simplified example of the issue. I meant check the contents of `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb` after the return.

Comment: Before I even read the accepted answer, my first thought was "the `IOError` exception must not be happening within the `try`/`except` block as the OP thinks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IOError` exception is being raised when your file is flushed or closed. Your code is not explicitly closing the file (it is being closed implicitly when the file object is garbage collected) and therefore your code is not getting the exception.

Change this:

```
try:
   open(..., 'w').write(...)
except:
   ...
```

To this:

```
try:
   with open(..., 'w') as fp:
       fp.write(...)
except:
   ...
```

And you should correctly catch your `IOError`.

For the record, the `with` block in this case is a shorthand for:

```
try:
   fp = open(..., 'w')
   try:
       fp.write(...)
   finally:
       fp.close()
except:
   ...
```

Note the explicit call to `close()` that will raise the exception.

Comment: Do I have to declare fp first? I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: @DougSmythies: sorry, I forgot the colon at the end of the line. Fixed